# Aiohttp: How to send bytes in headers?

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to send bytes as a header value over aiohttp:

```
payload = {
#ommited for brevity
}

encoded_payload = str.encode(json.dumps(payload))
b64 = base64.b64encode(encoded_payload)

# sign the requests
signature = hmac.new(str.encode(keys['private']), b64, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'APIKEY': keys['public'],
        'PAYLOAD': b64, // base64 value
        'SIGNATURE': signature
    }

async with aiohttp.request(method="POST", url="example.com", headers=headers) as response:
    print(await response.text())
```

However, I receive an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "get_gem.py", line 34, in 
>       loop.run_until_complete(get_gemini())
>     File "/home/thorad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
>       return future.result()
>     File "get_gem.py", line 29, in get_gemini
>       async with aiohttp.request(method="POST", url=base_url + payload["request"], headers=headers) as response:
>     File "/home/thorad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 692, in **aenter**
>       self._resp = yield from self._coro
>     File "/home/thorad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 277, in _request
>       resp = req.send(conn)
>     File "/home/thorad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 463, in send
>       writer.write_headers(status_line, self.headers)
>     File "/home/thorad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/http_writer.py", line 247, in write_headers
>       [k + SEP + v + END for k, v in headers.items()])
>     File "/home/thorad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/http_writer.py", line 247, in 
>       [k + SEP + v + END for k, v in headers.items()])
>   TypeError: must be str, not bytes

which suggests that I can't send bytes as a header.

Unfortunately, the service that I am using requires me to do so, or else it returns an error.

- I have tried removing 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'

How can I send bytes as a header through aiohttp?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `b64encode` returns bytes, but those can be easily converted to a proper unicode string. It won't make a difference with your server.

```
>>> b64 = base64.b64encode(b'...')
>>> type(b64)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> b64 = base64.b64encode(b'...').decode('utf8')
>>> type(b64)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the payload in ascii:

```
payload = {
#ommited for brevity
}

encoded_payload = str.encode(json.dumps(payload))
b64 = base64.b64encode(encoded_payload)
b64 = b4.decode('ascii')  # conversion back to unicode

# sign the requests
signature = hmac.new(str.encode(keys['private']), b64, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'APIKEY': keys['public'],
        'PAYLOAD': b64, // base64 value
        'SIGNATURE': signature
    }

async with aiohttp.request(method="POST", url="example.com", headers=headers) as response:
    print(await response.text())
```